# Conditions for having refractive index less than unity?

Tags: optics, refraction

Is it possible to have an index of refraction, $n < 1$, giving the "illusion" of a speed greater than $c$.

As far as I understand it, is only the phase-velocity (which does not carry any information) that exceeds the speed of light.

But what I would really like to know is, under what conditions it is possible to have $n<1$?

Comment: You'll need some unobtanium crystals.   Other than n= -1 (mirror reflection) and n<-1 for certain specially created optical materials, n>=1 is required by definition, i.e. n=1 in a vacuum.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are meta-materials that can mimic n<1, but I am not terribly familiar with the details & don't have much to give beyond that.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_refraction...I wonder is this what you mean.

Comment: I am talking about 0<n<1.

Comment: This can occur close to resonance frequencies, for absorbing media, in plasmas, and for X-rays [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Refractive_index_below_unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been reaserching some more, and what I have found is something about waves in dispersive media. 
(The wave speed depends on the frequency of the wave).
Source: (http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/Dispersion/dispersion.html)
Apparently when the wave is traveling with a frequency close to the resonans frequency $n$ gets smaller
than $1$. But only the group velocity exceeds $c$.